How to avoid rerenders when the state array changes?
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ChatLog } from './ChatLog.jsx';
import { GoArrowUp } from "react-icons/go";

export function QueryBar() {
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
    const [botChat, setBotChat] = useState([]);
    const [userChat, setUserChat] = useState([]);

    const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            e.preventDefault();
            handleSubmit();
        }
    }
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        const params = {
            prompt: searchInput
        }
        axios.get("http://localhost:5555/chat", { params })
            .then((response) => {
                setBotChat(botChat => [...botChat, response.data.result]);
                setSearchInput("");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert('Something bad happened while getting API response');
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        setSearchInput(searchInput);
    }, [searchInput]);

    const chat = useMemo(() => botChat.map(chat => {
        return (
            <>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <h4 className="pl-7 pt-2">Bot: </h4>
                    <div className="pl-24 before:absolute before:inset-0 before:animate-typewriter before:bg-white after:absolute after:inset-0 after:w-[0.125em] after:animate-caret after:bg-black">{chat}</div>
                </React.Fragment>
            </>
        )
    }), [botChat])
    return (
        <>
        <div className="h-screen">
            <div>{chat}</div>
            <div className="p-4">
                <div className="w-screen absolute bottom-0 flex justify-center mb-8">
                    <form className="w-1/2 rounded-lg outline">
                        <input className="w-full placeholder:text-gray-500 pl-[8px] outline-none" type="text" placeholder='Talk to Bot'
                        onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)} onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} value={searchInput}/>
                    </form>
                    <button className="mx-4 h-6 w-6 inline-block rounded-full align-center outline items-center" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                        <div className='flex items-center justify-center'>
                            <GoArrowUp/>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
    }

export default QueryBar

Seems like every time the botChat state array is updated by the API call, it rerenders the entire chat log as the animation occurs for all previous chats as well. How can I fix this? I tried to use useMemo hook but it seems like it doesn't work or I'm just using it wrong (probably the latter).

<> is <React.Fragment>, any reason why you're nesting one in another within your .map()? You should give your parent component that you're using in .map() a unique key that remains consistent each time you map the same element from the array. That should hopefully avoid the animation reoccurring.

useMemo wont work in this cases since you are updating the chat state with new values. Also this issue is created since you are storing the mapped values and then rendering them
Also one more issue is that you are creating an infinite loop here by updating searchInput state here and calling the useEffect again since this state was updated, so remove this part from your code:
useEffect(() => {
    setSearchInput(searchInput);
}, [searchInput]);

Also just render the mapped values directly inside the jsx, your final code might look something like this:
export function QueryBar() {
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
const [botChat, setBotChat] = useState([]);
const [userChat, setUserChat] = useState([]);

const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        e.preventDefault();
        handleSubmit();
    }
}
const handleSubmit = () => {
    const params = {
        prompt: searchInput
    }
    axios.get("http://localhost:5555/chat", { params })
        .then((response) => {
            setBotChat(botChat => [...botChat, response.data.result]);
            setSearchInput("");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert('Something bad happened while getting API response');
            console.log(error);
        })
}



return (
    <div className="h-screen">
        <div>
            {botChat.map((chat, index) => (
                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                    <h4 className="pl-7 pt-2">Bot: </h4>
                    <div className="pl-24 before:absolute before:inset-0 before:animate-typewriter before:bg-white after:absolute after:inset-0 after:w-[0.125em] after:animate-caret after:bg-black">
                        {chat}
                    </div>
                </React.Fragment>
            ))}
        </div>
        <div className="p-4">
            <div className="w-screen absolute bottom-0 flex justify-center mb-8">
                <form className="w-1/2 rounded-lg outline">
                    <input className="w-full placeholder:text-gray-500 pl-[8px] outline-none" type="text" placeholder='Talk to Bot'
                        onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)} onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} value={searchInput} />
                </form>
                <button className="mx-4 h-6 w-6 inline-block rounded-full align-center outline items-center" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className='flex items-center justify-center'>
                        <GoArrowUp />
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}


Your statement about why this issue occurs is not correct. The fact that the OP utilizes a useMemo or "stores" them or renders all the items when the state changes is not responsible for the creation of new DOM nodes. The missing key is.
You even set a key in your code snippet but didn't mention it. And as a general rule the index makes the worst key; if items are allowed to be removed the wrong nodes would get updated. The actual text content or a message id would be suited.

Thanks for the suggestion, i might be wrong determining the actual cause but my solution will work. Also i used index as key since using chat as a key might create duplicates.

Provide a key to each item so the corresponding DOM elements can stay the same and only new items will create new DOM elements.
botChat.map(chat => (
  <React.Fragment key={chat}>
    <h4 className="...">Bot: </h4>
    <div className="...">{chat}</div>
  </React.Fragment>
))

That said, your component code contains alot of unnecessairy lines.
You don't need to wrap everthing in <></> fragments, this is only needed if you return more than one top-level node.
You don't need to update searchInput with a useEffect.
Your useMemo is not needed here.

According to the code provided in the question, botChat is an array of string so using chat as a key isnt a good option here since it will possibly contain duplicates.
